# Choosing a blockchain fork in Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain-fork

According to [this](https://bitcoinmagazine.com/articles/bitcoin-beginners-guide-surviving-bip-148-uasf/#1496254102), the [BIP 148](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0148.mediawiki) UASF (user activated soft fork) goes into effect on August 1. Supposing it results in a substantial fork in the blockchain, is there a way users of Bitcoin Core can choose which chain to use (as opposed to whichever chain one's node receives first)? In other words: How do I tell Bitcoin Core to use an alternative chain?

Is this what [`preciousblock`](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#preciousblock)* is for?

<sup>*"Treats a block as if it were received before others with the same work."</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you linked it seems to me that `preciousblock` doesn't supersede a longer chain, it just prioritizes one block over another at the same height.

You could call `bitcoin-cli invalidateblock <blockhash>` on the first block of the chain that you wish not to follow.